# How to find what range a number is in

Tags: java

I have folders named like this:

```
"1-500"
"501-1000"
"1001-1500"
"1501-2000"
"2501-3000"
etc....
```

Given an Id such as `1777` how can I find the name of the folder it belongs in?

I am using Java, but your answer can be pseudocode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how:

```
// Folder 0: 1-500
// Folder 1: 501-1000
// Folder 2: 1001-1500
// ...

int n = 1777;
int folder = (n-1) / 500;

System.out.printf("%d belongs to folder %d - %d",
                  n, folder * 500 + 1, (folder+1) * 500);
```

**Output:**

```
1777 belongs to folder 1501 - 2000
```

The integer division will take care of the "flooring" required to get the right folder-index. **Be careful to include the `- 1`**. Otherwise, `n = 500` will end up in group 1 (instead of 0).

Comment: @org.life.java. I always compile and test before I post :-)

Comment: I generally do but I thought it was sure shot :p

Answer (score 3):

```
    int n = 1777;
    int temp = ((n / 500) * 500) + 1 ;
    if(temp > n && n !=0){
        temp-=500;
    }
    String result = "" + temp + " - "+ (temp + 499);
    System.out.println(result);
```

- [Here is working IDE One demo](http://ideone.com/kvQ29)

Comment: I think you meant `String result = "" + ((n/500)*500) + "-" ((n/500)*500)+500 ;`

Comment: You also want to add 1 to the first number (e.g. 1-500, 501-1000), other than that this is a good answer :-)

Comment: That won't work for the range he specifies. I.E.: 1-500, this will check for 0-500

Comment: A pair of '"' too much... Otherwise they way I'd do it.

Comment: Prints `1500-1500500` for me.

Comment: @org.life.java Now would you mind noticing that in the original question range is not 1500 but 1501? :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, we just need to update it for the 1 added to the first number

Comment: No, then it will print `1001 - 1500` for `n = 1000`. See my answer.

Comment: @aioobe @joe @Max @andy @Malfist thanks for pointing it out now it has been **fixed**

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more generic method, here it goes (based on the https://stackoverflow.com/users/276052/aioobe's solution):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3000; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + getRange(i, 1000));
    }
}

private static String getRange(int id, int step) {
    int x = ((id - 1) / step);
    return (x * step + 1) + "-" + ((x + 1) * step);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( folder in folders )
  [from, to] = split( folder.name, "-" )
  if ( id < from || id > to )
    continue
  // found the right folder.
```

Comment: Iteration is not a good solution, if you can determine the result directly by a simply calculation

Comment: Simpler solution than the other responses. My only addition is to 1) Create a Range object with isInRange(int input) method 2) For each folder create the Range object 3) Cache all the range objects so that you no need to recreate them every time

Comment: Calculation is not a good solution, if there is no defined way to calculate that. Question author **never** mentioned that folders are grouped by 500.

Comment: @dirk - it might be simpler but it has an assumption that the range is ALWAYS 500. What if he has variable ranges

Answer (score 1):

"1-500" -> folder 0
"501-1000" -> folder 1
"1001-1500" -> folder 2
...

Take (1777 - 1) / 500 using integer division to get the folder number.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your folders, split the name by "-", parse two numbers and check if your number is in range:)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a few cases, where you'd check if it's between specified values, like:   `10 < x && x < 20`

Answer (score 0):

If it's always going to be a range of five hundred you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
  if(i*500+1 >= x && (i+1)*500 < x){
    System.out.println("X is between " + (i*500 + 1) + " and " + ((i+1) * 500));
  }
}
```

Where the variable 'x' is the id.

If you have to use the folder names, you will need to read the folders names, split on the '-' and then attempt to parse them into integers and use that instead of my for loop.

Comment: You probably mean `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Still though. I don't think this problem should be solved with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function :

```
 public String folderName(int num)
 {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(1+(num-1)/500).append('-').append((1+((num-1)/500))*500);
  return sb.toString();
 }
```